# Android - Create dynamically a menu after a server response

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-menu

I would fill dynamically my menu item after a request at web server.

I have created my `AsyncTask` class, but when start my activity, rightly I obtain a 
`NullPointerException` in `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

It's possible create the menu after that `AsyncTask` finishes the process?

Comment: you can use  onPostExecute() after te asynk to do this

Answer (score 2):

When your `AsyncTask` returns the result in the `onPostExecute`, call your Activiy's `invalidateOptionsMenu` method:

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu%28%29)

That will cause the `onCreateOptionsMenu` to be called.

The issue now is to inflate `MenuItems` from your `AsyncTask` result (and stick them into the `Menu`):
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html